# Backup a single row of data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table called users, and I want to take backup of a single row before deleting it with date and time.

So whenever required that record, I'll restore it from backup.

By this way I can secure all my data, and no need to look up into backups of database which are taken periodically. Because sometime deleted records doesn't exists in backups.

And if I do soft delete, table going to be messy with wanted/unwanted records. I need my tables with cleared data. If I don't need records, just delete them and store them into some files for future use.

Thanks.

Comment: No need to Delete the data. Just change the status to 0 or null. Thats the pretty good way.

Comment: okay but this way my database going to be very heavy, that's why I need it. there my be thousands of records in database

Comment: do a soft delete instead

Comment: Then where do you plan to take a backup??

Comment: In a file, one file for one table like "users.txt" or "users.sql"

Comment: Is better to add a status flag in the same table?like 'deleted_status'

Comment: Just a few thoughts, What do you consider very heavy? I do not find a database table with thousands of users very heavy. 
Also, when you backup records when you delete them, how do you see this as a replacement for backups? The records that you do not delete are not backed up in this system.

Comment: users table is only for example, just to explain my question. I need to take backup of single record in a file before deleting it. So in future by mistake if I delete some records and I don't have that records in database backup, I'll take it from that files.

Comment: Best back up of specific data you wish to keep. Have a secondary schema with the tables you wish. Have a delete statement insert into the secondary schema to which you have your backed up data. Though there are many alternative methods for backups & it's in best practice not to delete from a table unless you are holding sensitive data which the client has request it to be removed

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new table like `'backup_table'` and when you perform delete action then before delete query you have to insert that record into the `'backup_table'` with same id and date time.

I think these can be helpful to you.

Comment: Not exactly, I have hundreds of tables and to maintain it I need more that much of tables :(